# Fetch data in list in descending order using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web-services

I am using a web service. I want to fetch last updated data on the top of the gridview using Entity Framework. When I am using order by descending method it shows an error on `ToList`.

```
public List<GetSet> GetItemInfoByInfo()
{
    List<GetSet> _lst = new List<GetSet>();
    GetSet show = new GetSet();

    using (DBSpotrackFormEntities dbContext = new DBSpotrackFormEntities())
    {
        _lst = dbContext.tblSpotrackLogs.Select(i => new GetSet()
        {
            Id = i.Id,
            Emp_id = i.Emp_id,
            Quantity_produced = i.Quantity_produced,
            Workdone = i.Workdone,
            Ideal_hour = i.Ideal_hour,
            Breakdown_hour = i.Breakdown_hour,
            Activity_code = i.AssestCode,
            Operator_name = i.Operator_name,
            Concern_name = i.Concern_name,
            AssestDesc = i.AssestDesc,
            VechileRegNo = i.VechileRegNo,
            AssestCode = i.Activity_code,
            Hmr_openingReading = i.Hmr_openingReading,
            Hmr_closingReading = i.Hmr_closingReading,
            Kmr_openingReading = i.Kmr_openingReading,
            Kmr_closingReading = i.Kmr_closingReading,
            FuelIssued = i.FuelIssued,
            DateFrom = i.DateFrom,
            DateTo = i.DateTo,
            Work_closetime = i.Work_closetime,
            Work_starttime = i.Work_starttime,

            Hmr_OpnClosDiff = i.Hmr_OpnClosDiff,
            Kmr_OpnClosDiff = i.Kmr_OpnClosDiff,
        }).ToList();
    }

    return _lst;
}
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<tblSpotrackLog>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GetSet>'

Comment: can you do orderbyDesending on `dbContext.tblSpotrackLogs` and then `select` ?

Comment: also did you called OrderByDescending after calling 'ToList()` ? that should have worked.

Comment: _lst = dbContext.tblSpotrackLogs.Select(i => new GetSet()
             {
}

             }).ToList().OrderByDescending();

Comment: `_lst = dbContext.tblSpotrackLogs.Select(i => new GetSet() { } }).ToList().OrderByDescending().ToList();` not working ?

Comment: It shows an error :No overload for method 'OrderByDescending' takes 0 arguments

Comment: which property in GetData you want to use for sorting ? Actually it should be something like `lst = dbContext.tblSpotrackLogs.Select(i => new GetSet() { } }).ToList().OrderByDescending(p=>p.propertyToSort).ToList();`

Comment: Which field do you want to order by?

Comment: on the basis of DateFrom field.

Comment: thanks rahul sir..now code is working

Comment: @VishalGupta : I am adding this as answer, mark it to close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
lst = dbContext.tblSpotrackLogs.Select(i => new GetSet() { } }).ToList().OrderByDescending(p=>p.DateFrom).ToList();
```

Comment: it should work absolutely fine. I didn't get it compiled before posting

Comment: In that case I would remove the first `ToList` since it will just slow things down.